# what should I add to display the value of fields correctly?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

what should I add to display user_id and cat correctly

```html
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record=super(test, self).create(vals)

        if vals['total'] > 0:
            vals['date'] = fields.Datetime.now()
                      
            self.env['journal'].create({
                'user_id': record.patient_id,
                'cat': record.cat,})
                ....
                .....
```

on the tree view (journal):

user_id is displayed as `test.user(6,)`
 cat is displayed as `cat1`

***EDITS:***

```html
class test(models.Model):
    _name = 'test'
    cat = fields.Selection(
        required=True, 
        related='test_type_cat.name',
        store=True,      
    )
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='user', readonly=True,)  
    .....
    
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        
        record=super(test, self).create(vals)

        if vals['total'] > 0:
            vals['date'] = fields.Datetime.now()
                      
            self.env['journal'].create({
                'patient_id': record.patient_id.name,
                'cat': record.cat,
                'user_id': record.user_id.name,
                         
            })
            record.total = 0  
        return record
```

why does it work with .name and not .id ?
for m2o field should I pass the integer value ? if it is the case why does it work here with .name ? and what about m2m and o2m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for you because you are creating a record in model: `journal` not in `test` model.

and if you go to `journal` model you will find that `patient_id` is `Char` field not a `many2one` field.

so if you pass: `record.patient_id` you are passing an object and it's converted to char this is why you get `test(1,)`. because `pateint_id` is a many2one field in `test` model witch mean is an `object`.

Hope this clear thing little bit for you.

Comment: `'user_id': record.patient_id.id, ` instead of  `test.user(6,)` it displays `1` but  `'user_id': record.patient_id.name, ` shows the right name

Comment: did you declare user_id m2o field or char?

Comment: m2o field .                                                                                                       `user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='user', readonly=True)`

Comment: okey I'll edit my post ....the problem is already solved but I just need to understand

Comment: learn and repeat every one is like you when learning new thing